# Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined' (2366)

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating common service in angular to use communicating with backend using HTTP
Creating following dynamic function to use header

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { from, Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Injectable()
export class CommonAPIService {

    private _adminHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
        public router: Router) {

    }

    public getAdminHeaders(): HttpHeaders {
        if (localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
            this._adminHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
                'Authentication': localStorage.getItem('access_token') || 'null'
            });
            return this._adminHeaders;
        }
        else {
            this._adminHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
        }
       }
    }
}
```

In public getAdminHeaders function got this error:
**Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'**

I also import httpheader from angular common library

Comment: You do not return anything in `else` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. `getAdminHeaders` is expecting a return type`(HttpHeaders)` but in else clause you're not returning anything. That's why you're getting ts error

```
public getAdminHeaders(): HttpHeaders { // <-- declared return type
  if (localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
    this._adminHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authentication': localStorage.getItem('access_token') || 'null'
    });
  } else {
    this._adminHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }
  return this._adminHeaders;
}
```